# Poisson reduction in odd/graded Poisson geometry?

Tags: reference-request, poisson-geometry, lie-superalgebras, supermanifolds

I would like to know whether there is any literature on Poisson reduction of $\mathbb Z$- or $\mathbb Z_2$-graded Poisson algebras.

A $\mathbb Z$-graded Poisson algebra with degree $p\in\mathbb Z$ Poisson structure $(-,-)$ is a $\mathbb Z$-graded algebra $P$ so that $(-,-):P\times P\to P$ is a degree $p$ linear map, on top of appropriately graded versions of antisymmetry and Jacobi identities etc. These arise in e.g. the Batalin-Vilkovisky formalism (for $p=+1$) in mathematical physics.

By Poisson reduction I mean the following, in the non-graded case, which is in some sense dual to Marsden-Weinstein symplectic reduction, when the Poisson structure arises from a symplectic structure on a manifold. (Summary to follow taken from [this n-Cat cafe post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/07/poisson_reduction.html), thanks Urs.) If $I$ is an algebra ideal in $P$ with
$$
(I,I)\subseteq I,
$$
the quotient algebra $P/I$ does not inherit a Poisson structure, but the smaller algebra
$$
(P/I)^I
$$
of elements $p\in P/I$ with $(p,I)=0$ does:
$$
(p+I,q+I)=(p,q)+(p,I)+(I,q)+(I,I)=(p,q)+I.
$$

Evidently this argument generalises to the graded case (and it's certainly implicit in the physics literature) but I have not been able to find any (explicit) discussions.

Comment: Graded symplectic reduction is treated in this paper by Mehta! (https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.1280.) I might write an answer when I've processed it